# Eclipse color does not change

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

I installed Eclipse for Java EE and My Eclipse, and both of them do not change the font and color. Every time I setup the color or restore the default color, the color turns back to all black.

For both Eclipse and MyEclipse:

1)I have a Eclipse for Android in the same laptop but it does not share the same workplace. Also, the Eclipse for Android just work well.

2)I set the font and color in Preference/General/color and fonts. I am sure I already clicked "Apply" and "OK".

3)I am going crazy. I have programmed for 3 years and now I feel I just back to the very first day I learn it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. To change background colour:

   - Open Windows>Preferences>General>Appearance> Colors and fonts
   - Select background color options, uncheck default, change to black
   - Select background color options, uncheck default, change to colour of choice
2. To Change Text colours

   - Open Windows>Preferences>Editors>Text Editors
   - Select element and change color

Finally make Apply and Ok

Comment: Think you... my girl friend set my system display setting as "High contract". That's the problem.  In this mode, every thing in eclipse EE is black and white.

Comment: Ok... If i help u please aproove my answer. Tks